# How do I pass props from one screen through header buttons in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am new to React Native and I am trying to set the property of `pollQuestion` from `QuestionGroup.js` and passing it into the next page, `PollDetailsScreen` after clicking on the right header button, `Send`. How would I go about doing this with `react-navigation`?

Here's a visualisation of what I am trying to achieve:
[image: App demo]

**App.js**

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { PollScreen } from './components/PollScreen';
import { PollDetailsScreen } from './components/PollDetailsScreen';
import { AppTheme } from './styles/Theme';
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { MainScreen } from "./components/MainScreen";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()

function App() {
  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <NavigationContainer theme={AppTheme}>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Main">
            ...
            <Stack.Screen name="NewPoll" component={PollScreen} options={({ navigation }) => ({
              title: 'New Poll',
              headerLeft: () => (
                <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Main')}
                  title="Cancel"
                  color="#617A67" />
              ),
              headerRight: () => (
                <Button onPress={() =>
                  navigation.navigate('Poll', {
                    pollQuestion: 'This is a question',
                    pollOptions: []
                  })
                }
                  title="Send"
                  color='#617A67'
                />
              )
            })} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Poll" component={PollDetailsScreen} options={({ navigation }) => ({
              title: 'Poll',
              headerLeft: () => (
                <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('NewPoll')} title="Close" color='#617A67' />
              )
            })} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**PollScreen.js**

```
import { View } from "react-native"
import { OptionsGroup } from "./OptionsGroup"
import { MultipleAnswersSwitch } from "./MultipleAnswers"
import { QuestionGroup } from "./QuestionGroup"

export function PollScreen() {
    return (
        <View style={{ margin: 24 }}>
            <QuestionGroup />
            <OptionsGroup />
            <MultipleAnswersSwitch />
        </View>
    )
}
```

**QuestionGroup.js**

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from "react-native";
import { useState } from "react"

export function QuestionGroup() {
    const [charCount, setCharCount] = useState("")

    return (
        <>
            <View>
                <Text>Question</Text>
                ...
            <TextInput style={inputBoxStyle.input} placeholder="Ask a question" multiline={true} onChangeText={value => {
                setCharCount(value)
            }} />
        </>
    )
}

const inputBoxStyle = StyleSheet.create({
    ...
})
```

**PollDetailsScreen.js**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { FlatList, SafeAreaView, StatusBar, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";
...

export function PollDetailsScreen({ navigation, route }) {
    const { pollQuestion, pollOptions } = route.params;
    ...


    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{pollQuestion}</Text>
            ...
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the `pollScreen` component to manage the state of the question and then pass it as a parameter when navigating.

first things first update `QuestionGroup.js` to lift the state up to `PollScreen.js` by using a callback function. This way, `PollScreen` can keep track of the `pollQuestion` state and pass it to the `PollDetailsScreen`.

then in `QuestionGroup.js`, accept a prop for setting the question and call it when the text input changes:

```js
export function QuestionGroup({ onQuestionChange }) {
    const [charCount, setCharCount] = useState("");

    return (
        <>
            <View>
                <Text>Question</Text>
                ...
                <TextInput
                    style={inputBoxStyle.input}
                    placeholder="Ask a question"
                    multiline={true}
                    onChangeText={value => {
                        setCharCount(value);
                        onQuestionChange(value); // Call the callback function with the new value
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        </>
    );
}
```

in`PollScreen.js`, manage the state for `pollQuestion` and pass it to `QuestionGroup`:

```js
export function PollScreen({ navigation }) {
    const [pollQuestion, setPollQuestion] = useState("");

    return (
        <View style={{ margin: 24 }}>
            <QuestionGroup onQuestionChange={setPollQuestion} />
            <OptionsGroup />
            <MultipleAnswersSwitch />
            {/* Rest of your component */}
        </View>
    );
}
```

Modify the `headerRight` button in `App.js` inside the `PollScreen` stack screen to use the `pollQuestion` state when navigating to `PollDetailsScreen`:

```js
<Stack.Screen
    name="NewPoll"
    component={PollScreen}
    options={({ navigation }) => ({
        title: 'New Poll',
        // Other options...
        headerRight: () => (
            <Button
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Poll', {
                    pollQuestion: pollQuestion, // Use the state value
                    pollOptions: [] // And any other data you need to pass
                })}
                title="Send"
                color="#617A67"
            />
        )
    })}
/>
```

you still need to get the `pollQuestion` state from `PollScreen` component and pass it to the `options` prop function. This means either lifting the state up further (to `App.js`) and managing it there, or using a state management library

edit:
as a reply to the comment this is how you can refractor your app using a Context:

```
// Create a Context
const PollContext = React.createContext();

// In App.js
function App() {
  const [pollQuestion, setPollQuestion] = useState("");

  return (
    <PollContext.Provider value={{ pollQuestion, setPollQuestion }}>
      {/* Your navigation container and screens */}
    </PollContext.Provider>
  );
}

// In PollScreen.js
export function PollScreen() {
  const { setPollQuestion } = useContext(PollContext);

  return (
    <View style={{ margin: 24 }}>
        <QuestionGroup onQuestionChange={setPollQuestion} />
        {/* ... other components */}
    </View>
  );
}

// In QuestionGroup.js
export function QuestionGroup({ onQuestionChange }) {
  const [charCount, setCharCount] = useState("");

  return (
    // When the TextInput value changes, call onQuestionChange
  );
}

// In PollDetailsScreen.js
export function PollDetailsScreen({ navigation }) {
  const { pollQuestion } = useContext(PollContext);
  // Use pollQuestion as needed
}
```

Comment: How can I bring lift the state up further into App.js? This seems like a lot of prop drilling, should I be using a Context in this case?

Comment: @JeremyChee both approach are valid. if you find that you are passing through many layers i will modify my answer to use context.

Answer (score 0):

Move header button interaction to its screen component using [setOptions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#setoptions) for full control of parameters. Something like this:

```js
function PollScreen({ navigation }) {
...
  React.useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <Button onPress={() => /* TODO */ } title="Send" />
      ),
    });
  }, [navigation]);
...
}
```

Comment: I used this approach but I am not having this warning in my console:
`Warning: Cannot update a component (`PollScreen`) while rendering a different component (`QuestionGroup`). To locate the bad setState() call inside`